# Show all terms excluding the current page

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

The following lists all of the terms, can I get help revising it so that it shows all terms except the the active/current page? Thank you.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'topics', array( 
'orderby' => 'name',
'order'   => 'ASC',
));
if ( ! empty( $terms ) ){
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_thumb = get_field('image', $term);
        echo '<li><a href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $term->term_id ) ) .'"><img src="' .$term_thumb['url']. '"><span class="model">'.$term->name .'</span></a></li>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    // create an empty array holder
    $current_tax_ids = array();

    // get the post terms
    $current_tax = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'topics' );

    // creating loop to insert ids
    foreach( $current_tax as $tax ) {
        $current_tax_ids[] = $tax->term_id;
    }

    $args = array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'topics',
        'hide_empty' => 0,
        'exclude'    => $current_tax_ids // exclude the terms
    );

    // get all the terms
    $all_terms = get_terms($args);
    // now do whatever you want
```

so if you follow my comments it should be clear, but basically you want to get the current post terms and store the id in an array, then simply exclude the ids when you do `get_terms` .